# Knockout validation hello world not running on jsfiddle

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle, knockout-validation

I'm trying to ask a question about async knockout.js validation running on page load, and I'm attempting to reproduce the issue on jsfiddle.

Thing is, I can't get the most basic example to work, despite having a more complex scenario running on my box.  What's wrong with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/C5rSm/4/

I have to post code:

```
<div id="vm">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: validatableField" />
    <p data-bind="validationMessage: validatableField"></p>
    <button data-bind="click: alertValue">value is alerted ok, but doesn't validate</button>
</div>

var Vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.validatableField = ko.observable().extend({ equal: 2 });
    self.alertValue = function(){
        alert(self.validatableField());
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm(), document.getElementById('vm'));
```

Comment: Which version of the validation plugin do you use locally? Are you using the minified or debug version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

However the current version of the validation plugin on (cdnjs [1.0.2](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/1.0.2/knockout.validation.min.js)) is quite old and it **has a bug** which prevents the `ko.validation.registerExtenders` working correctly. This bug [has been fixed](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/commit/ab033f91b833006c6327c550a8d2b43e5cb60e54) since then.

As a workaround you need to call `ko.validation.registerExtenders()` at the start of your fiddle:

```
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
var Vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.validatableField = ko.observable().extend({ equal: "2" });
    self.alertValue = function(){
        alert(self.validatableField());
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm(), document.getElementById('vm'));
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Bt6/).

Comment: Amazing to me that a year later, this is still the case.