# Knockout Validation: isValid always evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a quick example for Knockout Validation that I'm trying to get working, but for whatever reason isValid() on my validatedObservable is always returning true.

The JS:

```
var vm = function () {
    self = this;

    self.val1 = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: true
    });
    self.val2 = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: true
    });

    self.valid = ko.validatedObservable(self);

    self.checkValid = function () {
        alert(self.valid.isValid());
    }

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

The Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="value1" data-bind="value: val1" />
<input type="text" id="value2" data-bind="value: val2" />
<button data-bind="click: checkValid">Is it valid?</button>
```

Any ideas as to why self.valid.isValid() always returns true?

Comment: Which version of the validation plugin are you using? Because your code works fine with the latest version from github: http://jsfiddle.net/kFcHz/

Comment: @nemesv you are right sir. I was loading the version from cdnjs.com, looks like they need to update theirs. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Yeah, the cdnj version has a bug. You need to call `ko.validation.registerExtenders()` before using any of the validation rules: http://jsfiddle.net/SmBb9/ see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799242/knockout-validation-hello-world-not-running-on-jsfiddle/17802918#17802918

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout Validation isValid always returns true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256979/knockout-validation-isvalid-always-returns-true)