# Knockout Validation isValid always returns true

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am new to using knockout and I am trying to get the validation plug-in to work.  However, IsValid is always returning turn.  I have also tried
    ViewModel.errors().length == 0
but it is always zero

Here is the rest of my code, please help.

```
    ko.validation.configure({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null
    });


    function ViewModel(survey) {
        // Data
        var self = this;


        self.ProjectNumber = ko.observable();
        self.StandardName = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

        self.save = function () {
            console.log("Valid: " + ViewModel.errors.length);
            if (ViewModel.errors().length == 0) {
                $.ajax("@Url.Content("~/Survey/TEST/")", {
                    data: ko.toJSON(self),
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            } else {
                ViewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
            }
        };


    }

    ViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(ViewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log("Valid: " + ViewModel.errors().length);` notice the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewModel` is just a constructor not an instance of your implemented model. So you applied `errors` properties to constructor and also tried to validate this constructor that does not sense.

Change `ViewModel` to `self` in `save` method:

```
    self.save = function () {
        console.log("Valid: " + self.errors.length);
        if (ViewModel.errors().length == 0) {
            $.ajax("@Url.Content("~/Survey/TEST/")", {
                data: ko.toJSON(self),
                type: "post",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        } else {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    };
```

..and:

```
// create instance of model
var vm = new ViewModel; 
// setup validation for instance
vm.errors = ko.validation.group(vm);
// apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```