# Knockout validation not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to get knockout validation to work in a small form with just one textbox and one select field.

The jsfiddle behavior is not the same as mine. I get a validation for the select list but not for the textbox. the fiddle doesn't give any validation (but reports that `isValid()` is true).

I'm not a javascript guru and might have done something wrong. There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DzrqK/. The real page is loading the model in a bootstrap modal, but I've stripped that away for the fiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="AddApplicationDialog" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: Cancel">×</button>
        <h3>Add aplication</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" data-bind="submit: Save" id="add-app-dlg" class="form" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                We strongly recommend that you create different applications for different device types as it improves our error analytics.
                <strong>OutOfMememoryException</strong> isn't as important in a mobile device as it's in a server with a lot of resources.            
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Application name:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" name="Name" required="" minlength="3" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Application type:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select data-bind="value: ApplicationType" name="ApplicationType">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Mobile">Mobile device</option>
                        <option value="Client">Client computer</option>
                        <option value="Server">Server</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: Save">Create aplication</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind="click: Cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var AddApplicationModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.inited = false;
        this.Name = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: 'Please supply your Name.' } });
        this.ApplicationType = ko.observableArray().extend({ required: true });
        this.Errors = ko.validation.group(self);
        this.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.Errors.length == 0;
        });
        this.Save = function () {
            if (!self.isValid()) {
                self.Errors.showAllMessages();
                return;
            }

            //closing the modal and invoking a callback here in the real version
        };
        this.Cancel = function () {
            //closing modal in the real version
        };

        ko.applyBindings(this, $('#AddApplicationDialog')[0]);
        return this;
    };
new AddApplicationModel();
```

Comment: i dont get validation for select as well in your fiddle

Comment: @AshReva: Value for the default option is empty. Required select = an option which got a value.

Comment: What does the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin have to do with this?  Edited tags.

Comment: @Sparky: Because knockout validation is based upon jquery-validate and I do not know where the error is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are wrong in your fiddle:

- the cdnjs version of the ko validation plugin is quite buggy (see also: [Knockout validation hello world not running on jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799242/knockout-validation-hello-world-not-running-on-jsfiddle/17802918#17802918)) so use the latest version from [github](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)
- the `ko.validation.group(self)` returns an observable array by default so your `isValid` should look like this:

  ```
  this.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
      return self.Errors().length == 0;
  });
  ```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HG4cp/).

Comment: You edit made the select list work, hence behaving just like my local configuration. Why is not the text box validating?

Comment: ahh. it's shown when I click on the button. But why isn't it shown from the start as for the select list?

Comment: This is by design, the validation plugin only shows the validation messages when a property is modified. And because the `select data-bind="value: ApplicationType"` is two way it sets your `ApplicationType` which "dirties" the validation. You can have an extra `self.Errors.showAllMessages();` call after the `ko.applyBindings` to show the messages right after the start. Or use `this.ApplicationType = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });` to not show the validation also for the select in the beginning: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysy4V/