# Knockout decorateInputElement configuration

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I can't make *decorateInputElement* working on this very basic example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A6ktDrSfcrBTURyUGNNC?p=preview).

#### HTML

```
<label data-bind="text: isValid()"></label>
<div>
  <label>DateTime</label>
  <input id="datePicker" data-bind="value: dateTime" />
  <label data-bind="text: dateTime"></label>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$(function() {
  ko.validation.init({
    insertMessages: false,
    decorateInputElement: true
  });

  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.dateTime = ko.observable().extend({
      required: true
    });
  }

  var viewModel = ko.validatedObservable(new ViewModel())();
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

#### CSS

```
.validationMessage {
  color: red;
}

.validationElement {
  background: red;
}
```

Normally, *validationElement* class should be applied when the field is empty but nothing happens (*insertMessages* works, however). Any idea?

Comment: Please don't use the validation plugin from cdnjs it is obsolite and full of bugs. Use the latest one from github: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation http://plnkr.co/edit/uN4K0fHtCrYO5TadUfVD?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. Could you please post this as an answer so that I can validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please don't use the validation plugin from cdnjs**: it is quite old and [full of bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799242/knockout-validation-hello-world-not-running-on-jsfiddle/17802918#17802918).

If you use the latest version of the plugin from github: http://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation, then your code is working fine: see in this updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uN4K0fHtCrYO5TadUfVD?p=preview)

As a side note: you can make this working with the cdnjs version but there the configuration property is called `decorateElement`, so you need to write:

```
ko.validation.init({
   insertMessages: false,
   decorateElement: true
});
```

Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7t0jhmPMHN1VbCAgFmAn?p=preview).